# Async issue in call using ObjectiveDropboxOfficial SDK

Tags: swift, dropbox-api

I'm experiencing an issue with a function that should return an encrypted file from dropbox, but is instead returning the empty dictionary I initialized to receive the data.

I'm almost certain it's a race condition issue since an async call has to be made to the Dropbox API, but so far I have been unable to resolve the issue using GCD. Any help would be most appreciated:

```
func loadDropboxAccounts() {

    let retreiveDataGroup = dispatch_group_create()
    var dictionary = [String:String]()

    dispatch_group_enter(retreiveDataGroup)

    if DropboxClientsManager.authorizedClient() == nil {
        DropboxClientsManager.authorizeFromController(UIApplication.sharedApplication(), controller: self, openURL: {(url: NSURL) -> Void in
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
            }, browserAuth: true)
    }

    if let client = DropboxClientsManager.authorizedClient() {

        client.filesRoutes.downloadData("/example/example.txt").response({(result: AnyObject?, routeError: AnyObject?, error: DBError?, fileContents: NSData) -> Void in
            if (fileContents.length != 0) {
                let cipherTextData = fileContents
                let plainTextByteArray = CryptoHelper.accountDecrypt(cipherTextData, fileName: "vault")
                let plainTextString = plainTextByteArray.reduce("") { $0 + String(UnicodeScalar($1)) }
                let plainTextData = dataFromByteArray(plainTextByteArray)
                do {
                    try dictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(plainTextData, options: []) as! [String:String]
                    for (key, value) in dictionary {
                        let t = dictionary[key]
                        print(t)
                    }
                } catch let error as NSError{
                    print("loadAccountInfo:", error)
                }
            } else {
                print("\(routeError)\n\(error)\n")
            }
        }).progress({(bytesDownloaded: Int64, totalBytesDownloaded: Int64, totalBytesExpectedToDownload: Int64) -> Void in
            print("\(bytesDownloaded)\n\(totalBytesDownloaded)\n\(totalBytesExpectedToDownload)\n")
        })
    }

    dispatch_group_notify(retreiveDataGroup, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        return dictionary
    }
}
```

Just for reference, this the pod that I am using in the project:

https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-obj-c

Comment: What part of your code specifically isn't working as expected?

Comment: During the retrieval of file contents returned in the result callback. It seems to intermittently evaluate the contents before they arrive and then skip to the return statement.